# Nest.js save User object to Request in middleware best practice

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am working a nest.js application and I have a middleware that authenticates a firebase token and I map a firebase user_id to my database. In the middleware, I call firebase and get the user_id and then I fetch the User object from the database. I want to set the user object into the request object so that I use later on in the controllers. What is the best practice to do that?

```
      //middleware
      async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        const token = req.headers.authorization;
    
        if (token != null && token != '') {
          try {
            const decodedToken = await this.defaultApp
              .auth()
              .verifyIdToken(token.replace('Bearer ', ''));
            
            const authUser = await this.authenticationService.findById(
              decodedToken.user_id,
            );
            ---> req.user = authUser; //SOMETHING LIKE THIS
          }
        }
      }
```

I read a lot and there were a lot of conflicting solutions.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I ended up doing was somewhat of a "hack" an as I haven't found any solutions, nor I've found something that I could understand and didn't go over my head I'm gonna share this "hack"

### DISCLAIMER:

I **do know** that again, this is a **H A C K** and probably there are many better ways of doing this. But again, I'm gonna leave my answer here as it has helped me, if you know your stuff and could explain why what I'm doing is wrong, please say so in the comments.

### Answer:

```
  type ExtendedRequest = Request & { user: string; }; 

  //middleware
  export class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
     (req: ExtendedRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
       const token = "I'm a random, verified, totally legit token :)";
       req.user = token;

       next();
     }      
  }
```

So basically, just modify the type of "Request" , et voilà !, now TypeScript won't complain about "unknown" properties.

Comment: I think the best is to use the passport authentication module, but as you said I didn't find any easy solution taking into consideration I am also using firebase authentication. I will try this but eventually I have to try the passport strategy pattern

Comment: It will complain when you use the user property some where in your code. Something like this: Property user does not exist on type IncomingMessage